# How to do edit, modify , add & save the tags for a particular user

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have a requirement that once user logged in,there will be a page and custom portlet where user can see all the tags assigned to you and user has to edit, modify , add & save the tags.I googled it and tried some of the ways but i didn't get any idea.if anybody knows please guide me to do this.

This functionality already there in User-> My Account ->Categorization. By using below tag we can have a feature to add tags

```
<liferay-ui:asset-tags-selector />
```

But at the same time already tags are there in DB by bulk upload. I need to show those tags as pre-populated by using this tag.Then automatically it gives solution for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

We can do the above requirement by simple three tags as follows.i.e power of liferay.Very awesome!!!

**JSP:**

```
<aui:form action="<%=updateTagsURL%>" method="post"
    name="updateTagsForm">
    <aui:model-context bean="<%=user%>" model="<%=User.class%>" />

    <h3>
        <liferay-ui:message key="tags" />
    </h3>
    <aui:fieldset>
        <aui:input name="" type="assetTags" label="" />
    </aui:fieldset>
    <aui:input type="Submit" name="" value="Submit" lable=""></aui:input>
</aui:form>
```

**Action Class:**

```
public void addTags(ThemeDisplay themeDisplay,String emailAddress,String[] tagNames){
        User user;
        try {
            user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), emailAddress);           
            AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateEntry(user.getUserId(), themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(),"com.liferay.portal.model.User", user.getUserId(),null, tagNames);              

        } catch (PortalException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```